# vc++ force project dependency to always rebuild every time the project which depends on it builds or rebuilds

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, visual-studio-2019, nmake

I have a vc++ makefile project in Visual Studio 2019. This project has some dependencies on other projects (not references to them) within the same solution. In order the makefile project can be successfully compiled, it needs one of its project dependencies to be rebuilt always first.

This dependency project registers a library in the Windows registry and then set a value in the registry pointing to a path.

My makefile project reads that registry entry while compiling, so I need the project in which it depends to be always rebuilt first. How can I do this?